# When the left div slides down, the right div is pushed below it. How can I make them stay in the correct place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu that slides down from the top of the screen.  This menu features 2 buttons, which slide down their own menu from the bottom of the top menu when clicked.

The problem I am experiencing is when the right button is clicked, its dropdown menu pushes the left dropdown menu below its correct position. This creates a gap between the main dropdown menu and the right dropdown menu, as shown in the picture.

[image: Incorrect Positioning for Right Dropdown Menu]

I believe the issue here may be related to the display property going from none to block when the menus slide down. However, I have tried setting both dropdown menus to inline-block to no avail.

I am having trouble getting this to run in JSFiddle for an example, but it runs just fine locally.

Does anyone know how to get both the left and right dropdown menus to be at the correct height (attached to the bottom of the main dropdown menu)?

Here is my code:

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selector').click(function() {
      $('.dropDown').slideToggle(300);
      $('#dropArrow').toggleClass('glyphicon-arrow-up glyphicon-arrow-down');
    });

    $("#infoButton").click(function() {
      $('#infoDiv').slideToggle(300);
    });

    $("#searchButton").click(function() {
      $('#searchDiv').slideToggle(300);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.dropDown {
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgb(51, 51, 51);
  clear: both;
  z-index: 100;
}
.selector {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  transform: scaleX(1.5);
  padding: 4px;
  left: 49%;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, rgb(219, 79, 0), rgb(255, 185, 95));
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  color: white;
  z-index: 100;
}
#leftDrop {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#rightDrop {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#centerDrop {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
}
.dropButtonLeft {
  transform: scale(1.6, 1.6);
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropButtonRight {
  transform: scale(1.6, 1.6);
  padding: 8px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#infoDiv {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.8);
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 18%;
  margin-left: 16%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgb(51, 51, 51);
  clear: both;
  z-index: 100;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 1%;
}
#searchDiv {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.8);
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 18%;
  margin-left: 64%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgb(51, 51, 51);
  clear: both;
  z-index: 100;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 1%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class='dropDown'>
    <div id='leftDrop'>
      <span id="infoButton" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign dropButtonLeft" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
    <div id='rightDrop'>
      <span id="searchButton" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search dropButtonRight" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
    <div id='centerDrop'>
      Main Dropdown
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='selector'>
    <span id="dropArrow" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </div>

  <div id="infoDiv">
    Left Dropdown
  </div>

  <div id="searchDiv">
    Right Dropdown
  </div>
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle? I have not read the code, but you might be able to put the right dropdown in the html code before the left dropdown. Then and add a float right on it and a float left on the left one. Cheers!

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: I will try and make a JSFiddle again. I was having trouble getting it to run.

Comment: There are other coding playgrounds besides JSFiddle. Such as [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/). If you can't replicate on JSFiddle, try [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/).

Comment: I got an example working in Plunker here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/1uVVioQXgte13VcZWAGK

Comment: @bicycle_guy I recommend getting familiar with the inspector, and spending some time working with the fundamental behavior of HTML elements. We all have to start somewhere, and using 3rd party libraries can be a great time saver—but when it's enabling you to do things you don't understand, you can easily make something you don't know how to fix or change. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*A quick gif from the Chrome inspector:*

[image]

> *Some tips...*
>
> - The blue is the element
> - The green is the padding
> - The orange is the margin

---

### What’s Going On?

Each element is taking up the entire "line" it’s on, because they are **block** elements. There are a couple of things that change this behavior, namely using *CSS Floats*.

---

On your `#infoDiv`, you should:

- Remove `clear: both`
- Add `float: left`

On your `#searchDiv`, you should:

- Remove `margin-left: 64%`
- Remove `clear: both`
- Add `float: right`
- Add `margin-right: 16%` *(to match `margin-left: 16%` on `#infoDiv`)*

Compare the previous inspector to the new one:

[image]

Comment: This is an amazing answer. This is exactly what I needed to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#e0f8383b4f7e089f87b6784edb952540

This is just my attempt at replicating what I see in the image nothing more. Which is why I'm not using [`position absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

For the side buttons (left/right dropdowns) I simply used [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) to align them where I needed them. Remember [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)!

**EDIT:**
[Here's my fork of your Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/QlwPPdPWfYJEQJq2PvZx?p=preview): https://plnkr.co/edit/QlwPPdPWfYJEQJq2PvZx?p=preview

The reason why your right button was moving down when your left button's visibility changes is because by default a div element is [`display block`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

Meaning it will always present itself as a new line (like a paragraph).

So first you need to encase it in a new div (this will handle it's main positioning)

Then tell the left `div` to [`float left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) and the right to [`float right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

```js
$(".togglemain").click(function() {
  $(this).find(".fa").toggleClass("fa-arrow-up fa-arrow-down")
})
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Main Dropdown */
.maindrop, .leftdrop, .rightdrop {
  padding: 1em;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
  transition: all .2s linear;
}
.circletxt {
  margin: -0.16em;
  padding: 0.2193408em 0.48576em;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 25em;
}
/* Toggle Dropdown */
.togglemain {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.68em;
  padding: 0.68em 1em;
  background: #d6a12d;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
}

/* Left & Right Dropdowns */
.leftdrop, .rightdrop {
  width: 165px;
  background: #292929;
}
.leftdrop {
  margin: -20px 1.12em;
  width: 165px;
}
.rightdrop {
  margin: -18px 1.12em;
  float: right;
  width: 165px;
}

/* Click Events */
.maindrop {
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.leftdrop, .rightdrop {
  height: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#maindrop:checked ~ .maindrop {
  height: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: visible;
}
#leftdrop:checked ~ .leftdrop {
  height: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: visible;
}
#rightdrop:checked ~ .rightdrop {
  height: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: visible;
}


/* varaible classes */
.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.fl {
  float: left;
}
.fn {
  float: none;
}
.fr {
  float: right;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/4.1.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="maindrop" class="hide">

<div class="maindrop mainmove">
  Main Dropdown
  <label for="leftdrop" class="fl pointer circletxt fa fa-info"></label>
  <label for="rightdrop" class="fr pointer fa fa-search"></label>
</div>

<label class="togglemain mainmove pointer" for="maindrop">
  <span class="fa fa-arrow-down"></span>
</label>

<div class="wrap mainmove">
  <input type="checkbox" id="leftdrop" class="hide">
  <input type="checkbox" id="rightdrop" class="hide">

  <div class="fl pointer leftdrop">
    Left Dropdown
  </div>
  <div class="fr pointer rightdrop">
    Right Dropdown
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not explain properly.  The left and right dropdowns only slide down when their respective buttons are clicked.

Comment: Your question, "When the left div slides down, the right div is pushed below it. How can I make them stay in the correct place?". I answered that question. With the other question you just commented this answer would be a simple guide to solve that problem.

Comment: I got an example working in Plunker here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/1uVVioQXgte13VcZWAGK